Error ("bus error") running the simplest example on Hugging Face Transformers Pipeline (Macos M1)
I'm trying to follow the quick tour example here: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/quicktour
and i'm getting a "bus error".
My env is:

MacOS Sonoma 14.7, Apple M1 Max chip
Python 3.11.5
pip install transformers datasets evaluate accelerate
pip install tf-keras

Running this code:
from transformers import pipeline

classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
result = classifier("We are very happy to show you the  Transformers library.")
print(result)

And getting this result:

No model was supplied, defaulted to
distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english and
revision 714eb0f
(https://huggingface.co/distilbert/distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english).
Using a pipeline without specifying a model name and revision in
production is not recommended. [1]
92883 bus error  python main.py

Any ideas?
Thanks for your help.

using device=0 (the first GPU) solved this:
classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", device=0)
